# For the overused words, How to remove every other time it appears

Tags: javascript

there is a string called story. We want to gather some information about the individual words and sentences in the string.

```
let story = `Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful
bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack"
and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park
in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey.
is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived
not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised
in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem
Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software
like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.`;
```

- There is an array of words called overusedWords. These are words overused in this story.
- There is an array of words that are unnecessary. Iterate over your array to filter out these words.

```
let overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];

let unnecessaryWords = ['extremely', 'literally', 'actually' ];
```

the main question is **For the overused words, remove it every other time it appears.**

```
const storyWords = story.split(" ")
```

```
let reallyCounter = 0;
let veryCounter = 0;
let basicallyCounter = 0;


betterWords.map(word => {
  if(word === 'really') {
    reallyCounter += 1
  } else if (word === 'very') {
    veryCounter += 1
  } else if (word === 'basically') {
    basicallyCounter += 1
  }
})
```

I've been trying with:

```
let wayBetterWords = betterWords.filter((word, i) => {
  if(reallyCounter || veryCounter || basicallyCounter > 1) {
    !overusedWords.includes(word[i+1])
  }
})
```

Or this one:

```
uniq = [...new Set(array)];
```

But this solution removes all the future words in general that are repeated later, I only want it to leave the first time word and the next time remove it but only from an array of predefined words.

```
console.log(wayBetterWords.join(' '))
```

Can you give me a hand with this?

Comment: What's the output you're looking for, given that string?

Comment: Where is `betterWords` coming from? Also, don't use `map` for side effects. Use `forEach`  or a `for` loop if you just need to do something for each element in the array.

Comment: @Estebitan ... since there is obviously vagueness about how to interpret/solve the OP's question/problem, the OP should consider editing the original question towards more clarity about **all** the OP's goals/requirements.

Comment: 1/2 ... For instance, I personally would summarize the OP's matter as ... _"Within a text, how to count and collect word occurrence totals and how to replace every other matching word?"_ ... @Estebitan ... is this a more precise description of the problem? I also think a more precise 2nd bullet point should read like ... _"- There is also an array of words that are unnecessary. Iterate over the `unnecessaryWords` array to filter out these words and calculate each word's total occurrence count within `story`."_ ... @Estebitan ... agreed or not?

Comment: 2/2 ... Last, I understand the sentence about the main question as follows ... _"But the main question is ... **How, for the overused words, does one remove every other word (appearance/occurrence) from the text?**"_ ... @Estebitan ... d'accord?

Comment: @Estebitan ... The further participation of the OP in order to solve the OP's problem is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

An entirely generic approach could be based on a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) task which does the word replacement and word counting by utilizing [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) together with a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) which reflects the currently processed word.

Every word occurrence gets counted but whether to replace a word or not is determined by an optionally configurable `nthWord` property. It's value defaults to `1`, thus, either omitted or explicitly provided as `1`, every word occurrence gets replaced; a `nthWord` value of `2` results in the replacement of every 2nd matching word ... and so forth ...

```js
function removeEveryNthMatchFromTextButCollectOverallWordCount(collector, word) {
  const { text, counts, nthWord = 1 } = collector;
  let wordCount = 0;

  const removeAndCount = (match, leftCapture, rightCapture) => {
    // increment `word` specific count with every
    // replacement of the currently processed `word`.
    ++wordCount;

    // assure the correct replacement string,
    // either the match itself (no replacemnt)
    // or an empty string or the shortest
    // possible whitespace sequence.
    return ((wordCount % nthWord) === 0)
      ? `${ leftCapture }${ rightCapture }`.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
      : match;
  };
  // create regex which reflects / relates to
  // the currently processed `word`.
  const regX = RegExp(`(\\s+|\\b)${ word }(\\s+|\\b)`, 'g');

  return {
    text: text.replace(regX, removeAndCount),
    counts: Object.assign(counts, {
      [word]: wordCount,
    }),
    nthWord,
  };
}

const story = `Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful
bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack"
and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park
in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. literally. extremely.
actually. extremely. literally.
is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived
not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised
in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem
Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software
like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.`;

const overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];
const unnecessaryWords = ['extremely', 'literally', 'actually' ];

const overusedWordCounts = overusedWords
  .reduce(removeEveryNthMatchFromTextButCollectOverallWordCount, {

    text: story,
    counts: {},

  }).counts;

console.log(
  'result on `overusedWords` ...',
  { overusedWordCounts }
);

const {

  counts: {
    extremely: extremelyCount,
    literally: literallyCount,
    actually: actuallyCount,
  },
  text: alteredStory,

} = unnecessaryWords
  .reduce(removeEveryNthMatchFromTextButCollectOverallWordCount, {

    text: story,
    nthWord: 2,
    counts: {},
  });

console.log(
  'result on `unnecessaryWords` ...', {

  extremelyCount,
  literallyCount,
  actuallyCount,

  alteredStory,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: May I ask where in the question did the OP wish for the word count (not counting your last edit)?

Comment: The OP‘s example code very clearly shows the attempt of counting  the total occurrence of every of the word array‘s word. At least another answer (the one of Emily) tries to take care of this. And the OP‘s phrase … _“remove every other time“_ … means to replace every 2nd occurrence of a word.

Answer (score -1):

If I were doing this, I would split the story into an array of words, and iterate over it, each time I see an overused word, I would increase that words count. If the count is two (seen two of that word), I would just ignore that word when remaking the story.
Similar to this:

```
let reallyCounter = 0;
let veryCounter = 0;
let basicallyCounter = 0;
const storyWords = story.split(" ");
let betterStory = "";
for (let x = 0; x < storyWords.length; x++) {
  if (storyWords[x] === "really")
    reallyCounter++;
  if (storyWords[x] === "very")
    veryCounter++;
  if (storyWords[x] === "basically")
    basicallyCounter++;
  if (basicallyCounter === 2) {
    //ignore this word and reset basically Counter
    basicallyCounter = 0;
    continue;
  } else if (reallyCounter === 2) {
    //ignore this word and reset reallyCounter
    reallyCounter = 0;
    continue;
  } else if (veryCounter === 2) {

    //ignore this word and reset veryCounter
    veryCounter = 0;
    continue;
  } else {
    //all words havent been duplicated
    betterStory += storyWords[x];
  }
```

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient, but it does guarantee that you get all of your cases covered. I wouldn't recommend this approach if you have more than like, 5 overused words.

Comment: Hey that was a fantastic job

Comment: I'm eternally grateful for.   by the way this eliminates only the second repetition but if the word it is repeated 5 times the other times it does not eliminate them.

Answer (score -1):

You're on the right track. We can create a boolean that tells us whether the last time text was removed or not (I made a closure to scope the variable), then use `Array.prototype.filter` to remove the excess.

```js
let story = 'Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.';

let overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];
let unnecessaryWords = ['extremely', 'literally', 'actually'];

const words = story.split(" ");

const removeUnnecessary = word => !unnecessaryWords.includes(word.toLowerCase());
const removeOverused = () => {
  let lastRemoved = false;
  return word => overusedWords.includes(word.toLowerCase()) ? (lastRemoved = !lastRemoved) : true;
}

const result = words.filter(removeUnnecessary).filter(removeOverused()).join(" ");
console.log(result);
```